# What is going on with 'function pointer' or 'reference to function' as argument to function in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

In [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) they use something I've never seen done before, and couldn't easily find info on:

```
void fun( std::vector<double> derivatives(const double, const std::vector<double> &) ) { ...; derivatives(...); ...; }
```

Which I'm guessing is passing the function by reference (is this correct)? Why would this be favorable to using a function pointer? In which situation is each method prefered?

**I have a second issue:**
When I invoke the function for the first time the program hangs for several seconds. Now, the argument function I pass in, itself, invokes a different function from a function pointer  i.e.

```
  vector<double>(*pfI)(const double) = NULL;  
  ...
  pfI = pointedToFun;
  void argFun() { ...; deRefPointedFun = (*Theta::pfI)(t); deRefPointedFun(); }
```

What's the better way to handle 2 levels of referenced/pointer functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is equivalent to

```
void fun( std::vector (*derivatives)(const double, const std::vector &) ) { 
  ...; derivatives(...); ...; 
}
```

And similar to how

```
void f(int derivatives[]) { ... }
```

is equivalent to the following

```
void f(int *derivatives) { ... }
```

So the parameter is a function pointer. Functions as parameters are function pointers. And arrays as parameters are pointer to their element type. It is not similar to

```
void fun( std::vector (&derivatives)(const double, const std::vector &) ) { 
  ...; derivatives(...); ...; 
}
```

Which is a reference to a function, but only rarely used: It cannot be used for function pointer arguments, while a function pointer parameter can be used for function, function references and function pointer arguments.

Comment: As addition: Syntax in question looks more clear then using *-syntax. I think that's the reason why they used it.

Comment: Alright - that makes more sense. Do you have any idea why the program hangs before the call of the first pointed to function (I've done a trace and it's definitely waiting exactly at that call)?

Comment: I don't think thats problem with pointers to functions. You should post here minimal code that shows the problem so we could help you.

Comment: I think I'll grab some more info and open a new thread on the second question. Thanks!